How to set default foreground color in Bash shell?
I found the set default background color code from 
@user313992's answer:

On xterm-like terminal emulators:
This sets the background to a light green without having to clear the screen:
printf %b '\e]11;#ccffcc\a'


It works. But how to set the default foreground color in Bash shell in a similar  manner? Something like:
printf %b '???(default_foreground_color)???'

And, where to find the related information about the \e]11; code for the background color and the respective ??? code for the foreground color?

I found this color codes contains foreground and background, but it doesn't related to the "whole console": https://dev.to/ifenna__/adding-colors-to-bash-scripts-48g4

None is related to the console background and foreground: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-color-codes-can-i-use-in-my-bash-ps1-prompt

I'm tempted to unilaterally change the question title: You are surely aware that bash has nothing to do with the appearance of a terminal which can run any program you like? You are actually, literally and consciously, asking for control sequences for xterm compatibles; why don't you put in the title what you are asking about?

See https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf (page 34):

Ps = 1 0 ® Change VT100 text foreground color to Pt.
Ps = 1 1 ® Change VT100 text background color to Pt.

You already used 11 (\e]11;) to change the background, now use 10 (\e]10;) to change the foreground, e.g.:
printf '\e]10;#ff0000\a'

will set the foreground to red, while:
printf '\e]11;#ff0000\a\e]10;#0000ff\a'

will set the background to red and foreground to blue.
As @ubfan1 mentioned in a comment, if you prefer you can use color names instead of #rrggbb color codes in the printf, e.g.
printf '\e]11;red\a\e]10;blue\a'

